# If task start time is chosen from a uniform random distribution, is inter-arrival time exponentially distributed

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, markov-chains, queueing-theory

Question: If the start time is generated from uniform random distribution, is the inter arrival time exponentially distributed?

Context:
We have a number of tasks to be run every day (and we have the flexibility to set the actual start time). To avoid overloading the system by running everything at a fixed time, and we want to spread the load through out the day. And everyday we want to run the task at the same time.

To spread the load, we hash the taskid to generate the start time. (Almost equivalent to generating from uniform random distribution)

The question is, since the arrival time is uniformly distributed and independent of each other, does the inter arrival time follow exponential distribution? I want to use queueing theory to model the system performance, since exponentially distributed inter arrival time is the most studied distribution, I want to see if I can use M/M/1 queuing model.

I understand there are some differences. The start time generated is discrete, but the exponential distribution is continuous. I assume, I can increase the granularity of the time to approximate continuous time.

---

Another option is to generate the start time as a Poisson process (At every t, decide whether to run or not with probability p. ) But at some point, we want to ensure the task runs every day, so we might have to force it to run at midnight eventually. So this might get a bit weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the day is of length $1$, and there are $n$ independent uniformly distributed start times then this is equivalent to breaking a stick into $n+1$ pieces and there is probably a duplicate question on this site.

The inter-arrival times are not independent but they are identically distributed (as is the time before the first arrival and the time after the last, so $n+1$ gaps overall).  Jointly they have a uniform Dirichlet distribution.

Each gap actually has a $\text{Beta}(1,n)$ distribution so with CDF $1-(1-x)^n$ and density $n(1-x)^{n-1}$, with mean $\frac1{n+1}$ and variance $\frac{n}{(n+1)^2(n+2)}$.  I have seen this called a "reverse power function distribution".

If the day is not length $1$ but $d$ then stretch these results so the CDF of the inter-arrival times is $1-\left(1-\frac xd\right)^{n}$ and density $\frac nd\left(1-\frac xd\right)^{n-1}$ and mean $\frac d{n+1}$ and variance $\frac{n d^2}{(n+1)^2(n+2)}$.  For large $n$ this is close to an exponential distribution with rate $\frac{n+1}{d}$, as you might guess.

For example, here are the densities using R when $d=1$ and $n=100$, with the Beta distribution in red and exponential distribution in blue. They are very close to each other, and further right would be very close to $0$ (there is a slight distinction beyond $1$ as the Beta density would be exactly $0$ while the exponential density would be positive but less than $10^{−40}$). For larger n they would be even closer

```
n <- 100
curve(dbeta(x,1,n), from=0, to=6/n, col="red")
curve(dexp(x, n+1), from=0, to=6/n, add=TRUE, col="blue")
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand why the inter arrival times are not independent. Can you explain? From what I understand, the arrival times are also independent? If the previous inter arrival time was 2 minutes, it doesn't change what the next inter arrival time. An I missing anything?

Comment: The inter-arrival gaps cannot be independent even though the arrival times are, since the sum of the gaps is restricted:  for example one gap could be more than $\frac12$ day (with low positive probability) but it would be impossible for two gaps to both be more than $\frac12$ day since they would then add up to more than $1$ day.  There is a negative correlation between any two gaps, and you could simulate this to check.

Comment: This makes sense. I tried reading about Beta distribution - it is too complicated. I couldn't find how a uniformly distributed arrival times result in Beta distributed inter-arrival times. Also, how does this lead to Beta(1, n) of the beta distribution.

Interestingly, the Beta(1.n) and Exponential distribution had similar looking shape but with heavier tail.

Comment: On the last statement,
 "For large  this is close to an exponential distribution with rate +1/"

I am not sure on this. once the n becomes really really large, doesn't the inter-arrival time just approaches 0. Lets say if the granularity is a second, the inter-arrival time will eventually be either same second or next second. So why do you say this approaches exponential distribution? 
When the n is small, I do see the distribution gets close to exponential. Am I missing something?

Comment: @JackDaniels The two densities when $d=1$ and $n=100$ can be [seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJUnN.png) with the Beta distribution in red and exponential distribution in blue.  They are very close to each other, and further right would be very close to $0$ (there is a slight distinction beyond $1$ as the Beta density would be exactly $0$  while the exponential density would be positive but less than $10^{-40}$).  For larger $n$ they would be even closer

Comment: Which tool did you use to generate this chart with overlaying multiple distribution?

Comment: I used R and the code `n<-100;
curve(dbeta(x,1,n),from=0,to=6/n,col="red");
curve(dexp(x,n+1),from=0,to=6/n,add=TRUE,col="blue")`  - I have added this to the answer

Comment: Thank you. Accepted this answer. This is extremely helpful. And coincidentally, for my problem, being close to exponential distribution simplifies my analysis - we have n > 100,000.

Comment: I tried reading about Beta distribution - it is too complicated. I couldn't find how a uniformly distributed arrival times result in Beta distributed inter-arrival times. Also, how does this lead to Beta(1, n) of the beta distribution?

Comment: The uniformly distributed arrival times lead to a joint uniform Dirichlet distribution for the interarrival times, and the marginal distributions of Dirichlet distributions are Beta distributions.

Comment: Sorry to have too many follow ups, I promise I'm genuinely doing some reading before asking the follow up question.

Comment: I looked at the Dirichlet distribution and the Dirichlet process. Specifically, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution#String_cutting (string cutting) and  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_process#The_stick-breaking_process (string breaking process). From what I see, in this case, first a length is cut out with mean 1/(n+1). I'm the second trial, only the remaining stick is cut. The first piece is not cut further. In my question, even if the first cut resulted in very large piece, the first piece might still be cut randomly in the future trial.

Comment: That is, if the first random number generated is 0.5, then in the Dirichlet stick cutting process, it's guaranteed that one piece will remain 0.5 length at the end of the process. But in my example, the second random number generated can equally likely to be below 0.5, so the first stick can still be broken. That is, in my example, the order of the cut doesn't matter. In the Dirichlet process, the order matters. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Different string cutting methods lead to different or the same Dirichlet distributions.  This one with $n$ cuts at uniformly distributed points ignoring the others leads to $n+1$ pieces each with $\alpha_i=1$.  One way to see this is to start with a circle, make $n+1$ cuts uniformly at random and designate one cut as the start and end of the original stick.   Clearly by symmetry/exchangeability each piece has the same marginal distribution so you can then consider one piece as I did in my original answer to get this distribution

Comment: Do you have any document or tutorial that I can use to read and understand more about the distribution and specifically the string cutting interpretation